# one list a percentage of another

Tags: python, list, graph, plot, percentage

I'm trying to graph two lists where my TTS list is a percentage of Volume list. So for example, When TTS is 100, that's a 100% of 15 or whatever value is listed in the same position between the two lists. I'm not sure how to go about this and a novice programmer. I ran into trouble trying to uses lists and do percentages of one another, how should I approach this? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def percentage(percent, whole):
  return (percent * whole) / 100.0

Volume = [0,15,15,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]
TTS = [0,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,92,86,83,80,78,77,74,73,72,72,68,65]

plt.xticks([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
plt.yticks([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])

plt.plot(TTS, 'c', linewidth=3.0, label='TTS')
plt.plot(Volume, 'r', linewidth=3.0, label='Volume')

plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is it that you want to appear in the plot?

Comment: Volume looks correct when I plot what I have, but TTS shoots over Volume and back down, which it shouldn't do. I'm trying to plot that TTS is actually a percentage of Volume.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I put in my answer

Comment: Then it's probably correct, I just only saw one line when using that plot and not the TTS line. I appreciate your help and will accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to plot the following:

```
plt.plot([percentage(tts, vol) for vol, tts in zip(Volume, TTS)])
```

Comment: That's warmer, But I would expect the line for TTS to start heading down when volume is 40 and TTS is now 92% of 40, then TTS continues downwards as Volume continues up.

Comment: I think your expectations are off: 92% of 40 is still more than 100% of 35 so of course the plot will still go up.

Answer (score 0):

Use map:

```
def percentage(percent, whole):
  return (percent * whole) / 100.0

Volume = [0,15,15,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]
TTS = [0,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,92,86,83,80,78,77,74,73,72,72,68,65]

print map(percentage,Volume,TTS)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 36.8, 43.0, 45.65, 48.0, 50.7, 53.9, 55.5, 58.4, 61.2, 64.8, 64.6, 65.0]
```

elements of Volume and TTS passed to percentage function at the corresponding position, return value from percentage is stored as result list. For ex, 100 percentage of 15 is 15, similarly 90 percentage of 72 is 64.8 (3rd last element)

Comment: That's helpful and a great function to know. It's value's that it's output isn't plotting what I'm after so maybe I'm asking my question incorrectly, part of the problem of being a novice. For ex, 100 percentage of 15 is 15 (this is great and what I'm trying to plot) but I don't want to convert the other list into a percentage where 90 percentage of 72 is 64.8 (3rd last element). I want to show that at 95 I'm at 72% of 95.

Comment: You mean to say "I want to show that at 90 I'm at 72% of 95"?

Comment: When volume is 90, TTS is 72% of that 90. When volume is 95, it's 68% of 95. Not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: I don't think your edit was the intention, I believe your original answer was correct.

Comment: Yeah that works! thanks for teaching me something new! Is it possible to select two working answers? The only reason I'm select the other answer is that he answered first and provided the plot for it.